# How to Calibrate my Monitor?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, calibration

I have a Dell D630 laptop.

I just purchased a 23" external Samsung LCD monitor (which is awesome).

I immediately realized that my Dell laptop monitor colors are extremely wasted out compared to my external Samsung monitor, once I plugged it in.

How do I calibrate *just* my laptop monitor without effect the colors on my externally connected Samsumg monitor.

I'm running WinXP-SP3.

Comment: This question has been merged. If you want to know why goto http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18488

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer to that will vary depending on the graphics card of the laptop.  Usually the manufacturers drivers for your graphics will come with an option to change the settings for each display separately.  So if your graphics chipset is an intel one, download the appropriate software and use it to manage your display properties rather than the windows dialog.

Comment: The Intel Color Management is already installed within my Desktop Proprieties but it only appears that I can preselect from about 12 different color profile "files" to use and non seem to actually change the color at all.

Comment: It's not color management I think.  In the system tray next to the clock the intel drivers put a little blue screen, right click on that and you should get a graphics properties (not the windows one an intel one) and in there should be colour correction which you can set for each display.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Control Panels, open up Display, and click advanced.

If you have an Intel mobile chipset, then you can go to the Intel GMA driver control panel and choose "Color Correction".

Answer (score 0):

Just forget about your laptop image. It will never be like the Samsung. The laptop probably uses a low contrast fine pitch TN panel with the cheapest white led or low quality CCFL backlight. No way you gonna get a nice image out of that. Take it for granted and enjoy the Samsung for the colour critic work.

And if you really want to calibrate: try altering the angle of the screen. It probably does more to the image than software.