# SyncMaster 2693HM unnatural color over laptop's HDMI port

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, colors

I have got a samsung SyncMaster 2693HM plugged it to my laptop through the hdmi cable and I realized that the colors are different between the two screens.
When playing movies it doesn't bother, though the colors are different the movies on both screen are of very good quality, though the one on my laptop seems more real/natural.

The big problem is when reading on the syncmaster or browsing the net, or using a certain program (which means everything other than watching movies!)
Reading text causes eye fatigue.

One very evident difference between the two screens is the blue welcome screen of windows 10 where my laptop screen has a more darker blue, which feels better for the eyes.

my laptop is msi ge62 6qf (it has intel graphics 530 & NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M)

The question is: Has anyone had a different-color problem similar to the one I have described ? if yes did you find a solution ?

Btw: I have tried the settings mentioned in this site:
https://hardforum.com/threads/optimal-color-settings-for-samsung-2693hm.1310211/

Brightness : 17
Contrast : 85
Red : 20
Green : 12
Blue : 23

The result was better than other combinations yet it was far from satisfactory.

PS: I didn't try a different laptop with the monitor, thus I don't know if it might be a laptop-problem! However, the hdmi display should work as a plug-and-play without any problems

thanks in advance

Comment: So what's your question to us exactly?

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry I have posted it before finishing

Comment: "Has anyone had a different-color problem similar to the one I have described?" Monitors need to be calibrated to have colours match properly, this is normal and expected.  Your OS, monitors, and video card drivers should offer lots of adjustments to get the colours matching (or at least close), you'll just need to play with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calibrate two monitors to the same video settings](http://superuser.com/questions/36492/calibrate-two-monitors-to-the-same-video-settings), and/or [How to Calibrate my Monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/31360/how-to-calibrate-my-monitor), and/or [Monitor Calibration Tools and Software](http://superuser.com/questions/22832/monitor-calibration-tools-and-software)

Comment: I have tried the windows color calibration but it didn't lead to better results.
I will try the solutions provided in the links that you  have added in previous comments. It might help me refine my question/problem or even solve it.
I will be back soon
thanks for the fast reply

Comment: You don't want to do to the Windows color calibration, you want to go through the menus on your Samsung monitor and adjust the colors and settings there to get the two screens to match as closely as possible.